# Change image every second using PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

I have a small script written in JavaScript that is used to change picture every second. The problem is that image is not being changed.

The image file that shuld be displayed is overwritten every second, with the new data.

Displaying the first image on the webpage works fine, but getting all of the subsequent images does not work, always the same picture is displayed.

JQuery code contains time extension to force the browser to reload new image every time and to not take it from the cache.

You can see the JQuery code for image loading.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
            $('#image').load('camera_stream_worker.php?time=' + Date.now());}
    , 1000);
</script>
```

This is the return of the worker file:

```
<?php
  echo '<img src="/RAMdisk/image.jpg" />';
?>
```

On the picture ou can see the network traffic.

[image: network analysis using firefox]

So my question is: how can I display different picture every second?

thanks

Comment: Don't forget an epilepsy warning.

Comment: Maybe its a caching problem? Do you try to remove the image and add a new one at the same place with new URL?

Comment: So are you returning an image or html?

Comment: @Glufu How do you mean remove it?

Comment: load() will set the innerHTML of an object. This should work if you break the AJAX request apart from loading the new images. But I'm guessing you set up the PHP file to throw back an image on every request, which means you don't have to do an AJAX request and simply change the `src` attribute of the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### ajax method:

may need to specify different content-type in the header.

```js
$.ajax({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'camera_stream_worker.php?time=' + Date.now()) 
}).success(function(data) {
  $('#image').html(data);
})
```

Could be that the image names are all the same, therefore it doesn't get new ones. try to add a timestamp to your images:

```
<?php
  echo '<img src="/RAMdisk/image.jpg?<TIMESTAMPHERE>" />';
?>
```

#### this answer assumes the result were image srcs.

have you tried changing the src instead of load?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
            $('#image').attr('src', 'camera_stream_worker.php?time=' + Date.now());}
    , 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: (that will work if the php page is not returning an entire html document and just the image.)

Comment: @Henry Zou I hav trie you soulutio but it is not working in my case,´. Now nothing is displayedy

Comment: Then try to use ajax to retrieve the "image" html and then manually do a *$('image).html(ajaxResponse);*

Comment: Sorry, but I am not good with Ajax. Can you give me some pointers on how to do it? Thanks

Comment: added ajax example. this code is untested. see [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more examples and docs

Answer (score 0):

The issue here appears to be the fact  you are returning an html document instead of just the image that is changing. The HTML has a hardcoded `image.jpg` in the source and since that does not change it is being pulled from the cache.

What you would need to do is change that image source to fetch the latest image and not update the entire html snipplet around it.

Other option is to make the php append the timestamp to the html.